# `Deck` object has no attribute `all_cards`

Tags: python

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-bf17a4fca52c> in <module>
      5 
      6 new_deck= Deck()
----> 7 new_deck.Shuffle()
      8 
      9 for x in range(26):

<ipython-input-61-21d96db6d192> in Shuffle(self)
      9 
     10     def Shuffle(self):
---> 11         random.shuffle(self.all_cards)
     12 
     13     def deal_one(self):

AttributeError: 'Deck' object has no attribute 'all_cards'
```

Code:

```
import random

suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')

values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 
            'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':11, 'Queen':12, 'King':13, 'Ace':14}

class Card:
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank
        self.value=vlaues[rank]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + 'of' + self.suit

class Deck:        
    def __int__(self):
        self.all_cards=[]
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.all_cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
                
    def Shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.all_cards)
        
    def deal_one(self):
        return self.all_cards.pop()

class player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.all_cards=[]
        
    def remove_one(self):
        return self.all_cards.pop(0)
    
    def add_cards(self,new_cards):
        if type(new_cards)==type([]):
            self.all_cards.extend(new_cards)
        else :
            self.all_cards.append(new_cards)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return f'player {self.name} has {len(self.all_cards)}  cards

player_one=player('one')
player_two=player('two')

new_deck= Deck()
new_deck.Shuffle()

for x in range(26):
    player_one.add_cards(new_deck.deal_one())
    player_two.add_cards(new_deck.deal_one())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
def __int__(self):
```

It should be `__init__`, and because of that, the constructor is never called and `self.all_cards` never created.